# How can we make a POST service call which takes formdata instead of json in OpenTest?

Tags: web-services, yaml, multipartform-data, form-data, opentest

We have a WebService which takes `formData` key-value pair as the request instead of json. Using `openTest` how can we pass these `formData`? Basically we need a code snippet to post the `formData` using `OpenTest` yaml script.

Below is the sample curl command which we need to post  using OpenTest which has Content-Type as multipart/form-data

```
`
curl --location --request POST 'https://serviceurl.com/getacb' \
--form 'userKey=a1b23' \
--form 'apiKey=1_ffER_hk6Rb89--2EElfsdeF3' \
--form 'secret=Ude+6NIjojo89/gyAB7huGS5' \
--form 'targetUID=ulknnk4kjlkj5'
`
```

We are looking for a sample snippet to post the above multipart/form-data.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to build the FormData() object yourself before passing it to the next action.

```
var data = new FormData();
data.append("userKey", "a1b23");
data.append("apiKey", "1_ffER_hk6Rb89--2EElfsdeF3");
data.append("secret", "Ude+6NIjojo89/gyAB7huGS5");
data.append("targetUID", "ulknnk4kjlkj5");
```

This is the sample with some modifications from [OpenTest API testing YAML](https://getopentest.org/tutorials/api-testing.html#:%7E:text=Here%E2%80%99s%20one%20more%20example%20of%20an%20API%20test.%20This%20one%20calls%20the%20JSONPlaceholder%20fake%20REST%20API%3A).

```
description: Example Post based off SO Question
actors:
  - actor: ACTOR1
    segments:
      - segment: 1
        actions:
          - description: Create a random post ID
            script: | 
              var data = new FormData();
              data.append("userKey", "a1b23");
              data.append("apiKey", "1_ffER_hk6Rb89--2EElfsdeF3");
              data.append("secret", "Ude+6NIjojo89/gyAB7huGS5");
              data.append("targetUID", "ulknnk4kjlkj5");

          - description: Send a request to getacb
            action: org.getopentest.actions.HttpRequest
            args:
              url: https://serviceurl.com/getacb
              headers:
                Content-Type: multipart/form-data
              verb: POST
              body: data

          - description: Extract the response's status code and body
            script: |
              var statusCode = $output.statusCode;
              var postInfo = $output.body;

          - description: Validate the response status code
            script: |
              if (statusCode != 201) {
                $fail($format(
                  "We expected the status code to be {0} but it was {1}",
                  201,
                  statusCode));
              }
```